# Image upload in ajax and get base64 data

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to upload image using ajax in laravel. Here is my code

```
<input type="text" name="item_name" class="form-control item_name">
<input type="file" name="item_image" class="form-control item_image">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary store_new_item"> Save </button>
```

Ajax

```
$(document).on('click', '.store_new_item', function () {
var item_name = $('.item_name').val();

var data = new FormData();  
data.append('file', $('.item_image')[0].files[0]);
var size  =  $('.item_image')[0].files[0].size;
console.log(data);

$.ajax({
    url: '{{ url('/item/add-new-item') }}',
    type: "POST",
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    //dataType: 'json',
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
    },
    data: {
        item_name: item_name,
        item_image: data
    },
```

Laravel

```
  $item_image = base64_encode($request->get('item_image'));
```

**It shows error Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation in console** how can i get base64 data in controller ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please change your <input type="text"> bcz base64 is not file type it's a text type send

Comment: I want to send image name which is for type text and image for another input which is file

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = $request->get('item_image');
list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
list(, $data) = explode(',', $data);
$image     = \Image::make(base64_decode($data))->encode('jpg');
$imageName = md5($user->name . microtime()) . '.jpg';
$image->save(public_path() . $imageName);
```